# Calculate the cancellation rate of trip requests

Tags: sql

I have a table of taxi trip information and a table of user information as follows:

| id | client_id | driver_id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | cancelled_by_client | 2023-11-15 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | cancelled_by_driver | 2023-11-15 |
| 3 | 4 | 8 | completed | 2023-11-15 |
| 4 | 1 | 8 | completed | 2023-11-16 |
| 5 | 2 | 6 | completed | 2023-11-16 |
| 6 | 3 | 8 | completed | 2023-11-17 |
| 7 | 2 | 5 | completed | 2023-11-17 |
| 8 | 4 | 7 | cancelled_by_client | 2023-11-17 |
| 9 | 3 | 6 | cancelled_by_client | 2023-11-17 |

| users_id | complaint | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | No | client |
| 2 | Yes | client |
| 3 | No | client |
| 4 | No | client |
| 5 | No | driver |
| 6 | No | driver |
| 7 | Yes | driver |
| 8 | No | driver |

Normal users are those with the "complaint" field set to "No", while abnormal users are those with the "complaint" field set to "Yes".（due to some inappropriate behavior）

I want to calculate the cancellation rate for all normal users (both client and driver have not been marked as "Yes") in each day's requests.(I'm using PieCloudDB database)

For the given example data, the result would be as follows:

| date | cancellation_rate |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-11-15 | 0.67 |
| 2023-11-16 | 0.00 |
| 2023-11-17 | 0.50 |

For 2023-11-15, there were a total of 3 requests, out of which 2 were canceled. Therefore, the result is 0.67.
For 2023-11-16, there were no canceled requests, resulting in a cancellation rate of 0.
For 2023-11-17, there were a total of 4 requests. However, request with id 7 had a client_id of 2 marked as 'Yes', and request with id 8 had a driver_id of 7 marked as 'Yes'. Therefore, these two requests are not included in the calculation. Consequently, there were 2 requests, out of which 1 was canceled, resulting in a cancellation rate of 0.50.

I tried my query:

```
select date, 
    round(
        (sum(case status when 'cancelled_by_client' then 1 else 0 end)
        +sum(case status when 'cancelled_by_driver' then 1 else 0 end)) 
        / count(1), 2) as Cancellation_Rate
from trips  as t
where client_id not in 
    (select users_id from trip_user where complaint='Yes')
    and driver_id not in 
    (select users_id from trip_user where complaint='Yes')
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

But I get the error results:

| date | cancellation_rate |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-11-15 | 0.00 |
| 2023-11-16 | 0.00 |
| 2023-11-17 | 0.00 |

I‘m confident that my query logic is correct, but I don't know why the output results are incorrect. Can someone help me?

Comment: You're checking if the ```client_id``` and ```driver_id``` are not in the list of users with a complaint, but you're not checking if the ```client_id``` and ```driver_id``` are in the list of users who are not marked as **"Yes"**. This means that if a user has a complaint, they could still be included in the calculation if they are the driver for a trip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @koa, you have Integer division, it need to be converted to float division :

```
select 2 / 3  -- Integer division
-- 0
select 2.0 / 3  -- float division
-- 0.66666666666666666667
```

I have slightly adjusted your query:

```
select date,
       round(
         1.0 * sum(case when status in ('cancelled_by_client', 'cancelled_by_driver') then 1 else 0 end)
         / count(1)
         , 2
       ) as cancellation_rate
from trips  as t
where client_id not in 
    (select users_id from trip_user where complaint='Yes')
    and driver_id not in 
    (select users_id from trip_user where complaint='Yes')
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

Demo on [postgresql](https://dbfiddle.uk/Kj1LnsMr) (PieCloudDB is compatible with postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

In the PieCloudDB database, when performing calculations, if you use expressions like `2/3` or `1/2`, it will result in an integer division and output as `0`. To obtain accurate decimal results, you need to modify the query by replacing `then 1` with `then 1.0`.(Assuming that your query logic is indeed correct)